# Integrating Odoo12 with Alfresco 6 with Alfodoo

Tags: odoo, alfresco

I have followed [Alfodoo documentation](https://alfodoo.org/guides/short_guide.html) to integrate Alfresco with odoo, everything seems to work fine :

[image]

When I click on "Create folder in DMS" although a folder is created in alfresco an error is raised:

[image]

and no buttons to import files are showing, unless i **refresh** the page:

[image]

Here is my **alfresco-global.properties**:

```
# CMIS #
alfresco.restApi.basicAuthScheme=true
opencmis.context.override=true
opencmis.context.value=
opencmis.servletpath.override=true
opencmis.servletpath.value=
opencmis.server.override=true
opencmis.server.value=http://192.168.0.141:8080/alfresco/api/
```

Here is my **web.xml** for enabling CORS:

```
<!-- CORS Filter Begin -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>origin, authorization, x-file-size, x-file-name, content-type, accept, x-file-type, range</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Accept-Ranges, Content-Encoding, Content-Length, Content-Range</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
         <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
 <!-- CORS Filter End -->
<!-- CORS Filter Mappings Begin -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/s/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/cmisbrowser/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/definitions/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
   <!-- CORS Filter Mappings End -->
```

[EDIT]:

**CMIS configuration** in Odoo:

[image]

Comment: What are you using for your Alfresco CMIS root URL? Are there any errors in the Alfresco log?

Comment: @JeffPotts Please check the Edit, and no there is no error in the Alfresco log.